# Some questions about floating elements

Tags: css, css-float

I have two elements, #sidebar and #left-area. When I float:left them, #left-area appears first, how would I make #sidebar appear first instead of #left-area?

Comment: you need to take #sidebar first in html then #left-areal

Comment: do you want to share what have you tried in the question?

Comment: I moved #sidebar in html and it worked.

Comment: It depends on their position in the HTML flow. Please refer to the HTML and CSS guide...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS order property for this as long as you wrap them both in a container with display:flex;

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/am5wogq0/)

```
#sidebar{
display:block;
order:2;
}

#leftarea{
display:block;
order:1;
}
```

[See order here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp)